# regular expression to match a digit present n or more times before character and n or less times after it

Tags: python, regex

I need a regex to match a string based on two conditions using Python:

1. a digit is present *at least* **n** times before a `,`
2. The digit matched from condition 1 is present *at most* **m** times after a `,`

Note: there is only one comma.

For example:

`111,222` with **n = 3** and **m = 0** should return true because 1 is present **3 or more times** before `,` and **0 times** after `,`

`111,212`  with **n = 3** and **m = 0** should return false because despite 1 is present **3 or more times** before `,` it is present **more than 0** times after `,`

`111,212`  with **n = 3** and **m = 1** should return true because 1 is present **3 or more times** before `,` and **only 1 time** after `,`

I use `(\d+)\1{n,}` to capture the digit and check the first condition. But I am having trouble with the second condition. I tried `(\d+)\1{n,},\d*((?!\1)){0,m}\d*` but it is not working.

I assume that the `\d` after the `,` in the regular expression matches the capturing group that should not appear, any idea?

Comment: Your rules imply the `\d{n,},\d{0,m}` pattern. But it does not work with the supplied strings, so the question is unclear.

Comment: `(\d)(?:(?:(?!\1)\d)*\1){2}\d*?,(?:(?!\1)\d)*(?:\1(?:(?!\1)\d)*){1}$` with `{2}` being `n-1` and `{1}` being `m` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/YMETpn/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It needs clarification, but I'm almost certain they mean the same number in both parts - so `1` appears 3 times in the first part and 0 times in the second part (for the first case). The same for the remaining cases, but with different inputs. At least, this is what I gather from the second regex that the user posted.

Comment: @ctwheels yes! I just edited the question. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Hi @Toto, Python. Just edited the question with the language and further information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the pattern `(\d+)\1{n,}` if n=3 you will repeat what you already have captured 3 times so it will try to match 4 digits instead of 3 digits.

I would suggest not using `{0,m}`, but match an exact times like `{1}` or `{2}` etc, and after you have matched the backreference to group 1, assert that no more occurrences follow using the negative lookahead.

```
^(\d)\1{2,},(?=((?:\d*?\1){1}))\2(?!\d*\1)\d*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d)\1{2,},` Capture **group 1**, match a digit and repeat the backreference 2 or more times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `(?:\d*?\1){1}` Repeat matching the backreference to group 1 m times. Here `m = 1`
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\2` Match what is captured in group 2 to prevent backtracking
- `(?!\d*\1)` Negative lookahead, assert what follows is no more occurrences of group 1
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NpsWMy/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ib96MW)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^(\d)\1{2,},(?=((?:\d*?\1){1}))\2(?!\d*\1)\d*"
test_str = ("111,222\n"
    "111,212")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print (match.group())
```

Output

```
111,212
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Code

You're better to do this in code without regex by splitting on `,` and then counting the number of occurrences that one digit has in both parts. In python, it would be something like this:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##RYvBCgIhFEXX@hVvp4IM6Owi@5GhxWQNSc1z8Bno15vSot3h3HOPmp8R59aIwMEijDHaWiv0j4wVV45679usDd9iAoKAQHTirOjaPU10vEOW/aI4G4UfRekBCxvIMvn4wSy9gosDVLDiHWT927ODXY2aHSl0RWrwLT3WV2tf) - change the values of `n` and `m`

```
ss = ['111,222','111,212']
n,m = 3,1
for s in ss:
    x,y = s.split(',')
    for c in x:
        if (x.count(c) >= n) and (y.count(c) <= m):
            print(s)
            break
```

#### Regex

In regex, it can be accomplished with something like the following but it's really not ideal:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/YMETpn/2)

```
(\d)(?:(?:(?!\1)\d)*\1){2}\d*,(?:(?!\1)\d)*(?:\1(?:(?!\1)\d)*){0,1}$
#                       ^ n-1                                    ^ m
```

Since you only care that it meets the minimum requirement of `n`, we don't need to do `{2,}`